# How to move this giant that JavaScript creates up with this navigation menu css/html/js?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to move this giant that JavaScript creates up with this navigation menu css/html/js?

```js
function iscrtajVjezbe(divDOMelement, funkcija) {
    divDOMelement.classList.add('vjezbaokvir');   
    brzadatka = funkcija.brojZadatakaPoVjezbi;  

    let x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 15) 
  
    for(i = 0; i < funkcija.brojvjezbi; i++){    
        let y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)  
       
    }
    
    var c = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < funkcija.brojVjezbi; i++) { 
     div = document.createElement('div');
       div.onclick = iscrtajZadatke        
      
        div.innerHTML = 'VJEžBA ' + c ; 
        c =c+1;
        div.id = 'vjezbain'; 
        divDOMelement.appendChild(div);
    }
    document.body.appendChild(divDOMelement) ; 
}
brojZadataka = brzadatka;
function iscrtajZadatke(vjDOMelement, brojZadataka = brzadatka) {
    const activeClass = document.querySelectorAll('#vjezbain');
    activeClass.forEach( active => { 
        if(active.classList == 'active'){       
            active.classList.remove('active'); 
            active.style.height = '25px'; 
            active.style.width = ''; 
            active.style.overflow = 'hidden'; 
        }
    })
     
    vjDOMelement = document.createElement('div'); 
    vjDOMelement.classList.add('vjezbaDOMelement');  
    var countervjezbe,cvj;
    countervjezbe = this.innerText.split(' '); 
     cvj= countervjezbe[1] - 1;
    for ( i = 0; i < brojZadataka[cvj]; i++) {
       const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('zadatak');
        var p; 
        p = document.createElement('p'); 
        p.innerHTML = 'Zadatak ' + Number(i + 1); 
        

        div.appendChild(p); 
        vjDOMelement.appendChild(div); 

    }
    this.appendChild(vjDOMelement); 

    
    this.style.overflow=''; 
    this.style.height=''; 
    this.classList.add('active')
   

}
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#10EE67;

}
.head { grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 3; 
  background-color:#b3b3b3;
  text-align: center;
  color:black;  

}
.meni1{
  font-size: 25px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 height: 5px;


   }
   ul{
      list-style-type:none;
      display:flex;
      justify-content: left;
  
    }
   li{
      display: list-item;
      margin: 0 3px;
      font-size: 15px;
      
  }
  .container {
    display: grid; 
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
    grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 1.2fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 0.3fr 1.7fr;  

  }


.vjezbe {
  display: inline; 
  width: 500px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
  grid-template-rows: 0.5fr 0.5fr 0.5fr 0.5fr 0.5fr 1fr 0.5fr; 
  display: block;
padding: 5px;
margin: 0px;
   
}
.vjezba1 { grid-area: vjezba1;  background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;}
.vj1 { grid-area: vj1; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center; }
.vjezba2 { grid-area: vjezba2; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;}
.vjezba3 { grid-area: vjezba3;background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center; }
.vjezba4 { grid-area: vjezba4; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;}
.vjezba5 { grid-area: vjezba5;background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center; }
.vjezba6 { grid-area: vjezba6; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;}


.graf {
  display: grid; 
  margin-left: 100px;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ; 
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ; 
  grid-template-areas: 
    "graf1 graf2 "
    "graf3 graf4" ; 
 background-color: #2196F3;
}
.graf1 { grid-area: graf1; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  
 }
.graf2 { grid-area: graf2; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;

}
.graf3 { grid-area: graf3; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
  }
.graf4 { grid-area: graf4; background-color: gainsboro;
  border: 5px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
  padding: 25px;
 }

  img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .vjezbaokvir{
    width:500px;
    padding:5px;

    color:black;
    background-color: gainsboro;   
    font-weight: bold;
}
#vjezbain {
    width:100%;
    background-color: lightblue;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-top:8px;
    font-size:20px; 
}
.vjezbaDOMelement{
    display: flex;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-top:20px;}
.active{
    height: 80px;
    color: yellowgreen;
}
.zadatak{
   color: black;
    background-color: cornflowerblue;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align:center;
   margin-left: 5px;
   margin-top: 2px;
   margin-bottom:6px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    font-weight: bold;
}



  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    body {
      background-color:sandybrown;
    
    }
   
    
    .container {
      display: block; 
    grid-auto-columns: 1fr; 
    grid-template-columns: 0.8fr 1.2fr; 
    grid-template-rows: 0.3fr 1.7fr;  
   
    }
    .graf {
      display: inline-block; 
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr ; 
      grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr ; 
      grid-template-areas: 
        "graf1 graf2 "
        "graf3 graf4" ; 
        margin-top: 15px;
      
    }
    .graf1 { grid-area: graf1; ;
      padding: 25px;

     }
    .graf2 { grid-area: graf2; background-color: gainsboro;
      padding: 25px;
    
    }
    .graf3 { grid-area: graf3; background-color: gainsboro;
      padding: 25px;
      }
    .graf4 { grid-area: graf4; background-color: gainsboro;
      padding: 25px;
     }
     img {
      display: inline;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid red;

    }
    table.table2{
      border: 1px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
      width: auto;
      padding: 5px;

    } 
      table.table2 td{
        border: 2px solid rgb(67, 119, 163);
        border-collapse: collapse;
        background-color: rgb(150, 186, 213);
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 12px;
        padding: 10px;

      }

  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Web Tehnologije</TITLE>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="vjezbepage.css">
    </HEAD>
    <body> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="head"> 
        <div class="meni1">Welcome</div>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Grupe</a></li>
              <li><a href="vjezba2.html">Vjezbe</a></li>
             </ul>
            </div> 
            <div class="vjezbe">
              <script type="text/javascript" src="spirala3.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript" src="mojprimjer.js"></script>
      
             
            </div>
            <div class="graf">

             
              <div class="graf1"><img src="Graf.png" alt="grafik" width="450" height="250"></div>
              <div class="graf2"><img src="Graf.png" alt="grafik" width="450" height="250"></div>
              <div class="graf3"><img src="Graf.png" alt="grafik" width="450" height="250"></div>
              <div class="graf4"><img src="Graf.png" alt="grafik" width="450" height="250"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </body> 
        </HTML>
```

How to move this div that JavaScript creates up with this navigation menu?
I had code from before that showed the exercises and pictures on page 4, then I did over  to draw div for those exercises and create java script div tags. Now that I've inserted it fix it

Comment: Where does Java create anything here?

Comment: @mkrieger1 my mistake,  I wrote js code , which automatic create divs , but i can not insert in html and set good postion